# Titanium Image solarized in imageView

Tags: ios, imageview, titanium

[image: screen shot]

i am facing very weird behaviour in titanium. i have placed an imageview which loads a remote image. it was working fine and it still works fine on iOS 6.1 . but on iOS 7.x it shows solarized as shown in the attached screen shot.

anybody have any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: Which sdk you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably there is an issue with your image resizing technique. try to refresh images on server. it will correct the issue